# Compact surface with constant strictly positive curvature is a sphere

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-forms, surfaces

I'm following Cartan's Differential forms. I'm trying to do exercise 8 on page 161. The chapter is about moving frames and differential forms in surface theory.

> Consider the frame of Ex. 2 (principal frame), show that if $dk_1 = dk_2 = 0$ at the point M, then at M $k_1 = k_2$ or $\omega_{12} = 0$. Deduce that on a surface S  which has constant strictly positive gaussian curvature K, the principal curvature cannot have a relative maximum or minimum at a point which is not umbilical.

For the first part all ok. In fact we have

> $\omega_{13} = k_1\omega_1 \\ \omega_{23} = k_2\omega_2 \\ d\omega_1 = -\omega_2\wedge\omega_{12} \\ d\omega_2 = \omega_1\wedge\omega_{12} \\ d\omega_{12} = -k_1k_2\omega_1\wedge\omega_2 \\ d\omega_{13} = k_2d\omega_1 \\ d\omega_{23} = k_1d\omega_2$

Differentiating the first two and substituting the last two

> $ d\omega_{13} = dk_1\wedge\omega_1 + k_1d\omega_1 = k_2d\omega_1 \\ d\omega_{23} = dk_2\wedge\omega_2 + k_2d\omega_2 = k_1d\omega_2$

we obtain

> $dk_1\wedge\omega_1 = (k_2 - k_1)d\omega_1 \\ dk_2\wedge\omega_2 = (k_1 - k_2)d\omega_2 $

So if $dk_1 = dk_2 = 0$ we have or $k_1 = k_2$ or $d\omega_1 = d\omega_2 = 0$ and so or $k_1 = k_2$ or $\omega_{12} = 0$.

Now suppose that M is not umbilical, so $k_1 \neq k_2$ and $\omega_{12} = 0$. The frame becomes at M

> $\omega_{12} = 0 \\ \omega_{13} = k_1\omega_1 \\ \omega_{23} = k_2\omega_2 \\ d\omega_1 = 0 \\ d\omega_2 = 0 \\ d\omega_{12} = -k_1k_2\omega_1\wedge\omega_2 \\ d\omega_{13} = 0 \\ d\omega_{23} = 0$

Now I don't know how to continue to get a contradiction. I know I have to show that $k_1k_2 \leq 0$, against the hypothesis. I also know the solution working in local coordinates, but I don't know how can I translate this in the language of differential forms. The proof here is from Shifrin's book

[image]

I don't know how to get second derivatives with differential forms (because $d^2\omega = 0$), but I suppose (and also I prefer) I have to work avoiding local coordinates.

Thanks in advance

Comment: So is Cartan being explicit and saying (as in Hilbert's Lemma, which you've quoted from my text) that the smaller principal curvature has a local minimum and the larger principal curvature has a local maximum? Your statement of the question does not include these details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even with the moving frames computation, you're going to have to do something analogous to the local computation with second-order partial derivatives. How else can we check that a critical point is a local maximum/minimum?

Here's how you should start: Write $dk_i = \sum\limits_j k_{ij}\omega_j$ (so we know that $k_{ij} = 0$ at $M$ for $i,j=1,2$). Then write $dk_{ij} = \sum\limits_\ell k_{ij\ell}\omega_\ell$. If $k_1>k_2$ locally, then we know that $k_{1jj} \le 0$ and $k_{2jj}\ge 0$ at $M$ for $j=1,2$.

I would rather write your third displayed equations as 
\begin{align*}
dk_1\wedge\omega_1 &= (k_2-k_1)\omega_{12}\wedge\omega_2 \\
dk_2\wedge\omega_2 &= (k_1-k_2)\omega_1\wedge\omega_{12}.
\end{align*}
Solve these to obtain $(k_1-k_2)\omega_{12} = A\omega_1+B\omega_2$. Now can you proceed?

Comment: I get $A = k_{12}$ and $B = k_{21}$. Then differentiating your last equation I obtain at M $ -(k_1 - k_2)k_1k_2 = -k_{122}+k_{211}$, which is a contradiction since the LHS is $\lt 0$ and the RHS is $\geq 0$. Thank you very very much! I know I had to take the second derivative, but I didn't know how to do it! The "trick" you used - write the differential $dk_i$ with respect of the dual basis and then differentiate the _coefficients_ $k_{ij}$ instead of the whole 1-form - is great! Thank you again!

Comment: Is this the standard way to get second derivatives using differential forms?

Comment: Pretty much, yes. It corresponds locally, if you like, to taking the (co)tangent bundle of the (co)tangent bundle.

Comment: Could you expand this a little bit?

Comment: You might start with [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jet_bundle), but don't get too carried away. If you haven't thought about vector bundles much, I suggest waiting. Intuitively, I just meant that if you think of  $1$-form $\omega$ as a section of $T^*X$, then the cotangent space to the fiber of $T^*X$ at $\omega(p)=\sum a_i(p)dx^i(p)$ will consist (locally) of derivatives of $a_i$ at $p$. You can think about local coordinates for $T^*X$, $n=\dim X$ coming from $X$ and $n$ coming from the coefficients of a $1$-form with respect to a basis (in our set up, that was the $\omega_i$).

Comment: That's too complicate to me, sorry.. These intrigue me: "Jets may also be seen as the coordinate free versions of Taylor expansions" and were an advance on the method (prolongation) of Élie Cartan, of dealing geometrically with higher derivatives", but I cannot understand the article. Thank you anyway and thank you again for the answer!

Comment: One last question: why $k_{1ii} \leq 0$ and not $k_{111}k_{122}-k_{112}^2 \geq 0$ (det) and $k_{111}+k_{122} \leq 0$ (trace) ? I mean: what you wrote is clear to me if $k_{112} = 0$, but it is $k_{112} = 0$?

Comment: This is just the usual second derivative test. If $f(x,y)$ has a local maximum at the origin, then $f_{xx}(0)\le 0$ and $f_{yy}(0)\le 0$ [this follows from single-variable calculus, in fact]. You're right that the determinant condition $f_{xx}(0)f_{yy}(0)-f_{xy}(0)^2\ge 0$ also holds. Note that with the determinant condition, we deduce that $f_{xx}(0)$ and $f_{yy}(0)$ must have the same sign, and so the trace condition tells us what that sign must be.

Comment: What a stupid! You are right, thank you